# SQL Get 3 letters from a String into column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a given Column A and I can extract the First 3 letters of it using the LEFT function in SQL my problem comes in how to put this into a New column into the same table (table A) here is the Code for extracting the 3 letters. The column does not exist and I am s using MSSQL 2016

```
Select Left(ColA,3) As NewCol from TableA
```

Comment: Does the column already exist? What database are you using? MSSQL?

Comment: Edit your question and tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Edited per requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column is already declared, you use `update`:

```
update tablea
    set newcol = Left(ColA, 3);
```

If the column doesn't exist, then you need to add it.  So, you would first do:

```
alter tablea add column newcol varchar(3);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I saw the problem in my logic, I was trying to get te  data first and then   add the column. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the column already exists:

```
update [Table A] set ColB = Left(ColA, 3)
```